# Convert spaces to new lines in a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert all white spaces to new line in a text file so I will have a list of all the words in the text in the end.

```
with open('keywords.txt', 'w+') as g:
    replace = string.replace(" ","\n")
    replace.writelines
```

This is not working for me sadly.

I'm open for any tips or ideas, I can't believe that I can't get something to work that requires 3-5 lines of code.

Comment: Why are you bumping like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'w+' will empty your file and you never read in the current contents and string.replace does not work like that.

```py
with open('keywords.txt', 'r+') as g:
    s = g.read()
    s = s.replace(" ", "\n")
    g.seek(0)
    g.truncate()
    g.write(s)
```

Comment: I suspect that if there are multiple contiguous whitespace characters, these should be replaced with only a single newline. I would be inclined to use `s = '\n'.join(s.split()) + '\n'` instead.